# JS absolute position conflicts with my div

Tags: javascript, text, position, absolute

When I give some text an absolute position (using JS), it seems to lose some properties it had in its div. The main issue is that the text won't wrap anymore, and will instead go beyond the div limits.

Here's the full code arranged so you can just copy-paste if you wanna try (no css needed):

```html
<head>
  <script>
    var longtext;

    function positionText() {
      document.getElementById("longtext").style.position = "absolute";
      document.getElementById("longtext").style.top = 200 + "px";
    }
  </script>
</head>


<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">

      <div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;">
        Some text to fill this div, as you can see it will wrap by itself unless your monitor is fricken huge

        <span id="longtext">Long text that starts at a certain height, and has to be wrapped to remain within this div width</span>
      </div>

      <div id="mid" style="float:left; width:70%;" ;>
        <h2> Some head </h2>
        <p>Some text 1</p>
        <p>Some text 2</p>
        <p>Some text 3</p>
        <p>Some text 3</p>
        <p>Some text 3</p>
        <p>Some text 3</p>
        <p>Some text 3</p>
      </div>

      <div id="right" style="float:left; width:15%;">
        Rrrrrrrright
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    positionText()
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Absolutely positioned elements can overlap other elements.
```

[Solved Click to see](http://jsfiddle.net/jWknY/)

Solution is two nest absolute content in another div

```
<div class="floated">
 <div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="AbsoluteContent">
    stuff
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```